# MySQL: Substract Timestamp for Different IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, date, timestamp

Let's say I have one table with an ID, timestamp and an event.

For example: I habe a Book with the ID 1, another with ID 2. Both are lent at a specific timestamp, marked in the table by event 1.

Then Both are returned with event 2. So how can i find out the lending period for each of the books? I cant find an answer and i'm becoming crazy!

Table

```
ID   |   Timestamp   |   Event
-------------------------------
a1   |  2013-10-23   |    1
a2   |  2013-10-23   |    1
a1   |  2013-10-25   |    2
a2   |  2013-10-26   |    2
```

Result

```
ID   |   Days lent   |
-----------------------
a1   |      2        | 
a2   |      3        |
```

---

I dont have a better explanation, sorry. Every Subquery i tried results in an error with "more than one row".

I tried TIMESTAMPDIFF in subquerys, i tried to substract two querys. There are of course many different IDs, but the structure is exactly as posted

Comment: What is the datatype of `timestamp` column? Is it a `DATE`?

Comment: It's directly a timestamp. I've also tried to convert it. But it failed the second i tried to calculate the differences for each ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  id,   
  DATEDIFF(
    MAX(CASE WHEN Event=2 THEN Timestamp END),
    MIN(CASE WHEN Event=1 THEN Timestamp END)) AS days_lent
FROM
  schedule
GROUP BY
  id
```

Answer (score 1):

In your design, you have insufficient data to do the calculations. E.g. If the book `a1` is issued again, you would just insert another event `3`, which would then create a confusion, like which of event 1, 2 and 3 are issue event and which are return event.

To solve this, I propose the following.

Use same event IDs for the issue/return event pair. 
Add new indicator to show which kind of record is it, issue or return.

E.g.

```
ID   |   Timestamp   |   Event | Type
---------------------------------------
a1   |  2013-10-23   |    1    | Issue
a2   |  2013-10-23   |    1    | Issue
a1   |  2013-10-25   |    1    | Return
a1   |  2013-10-26   |    1    | Return
```

So in this case the query would be

```
Select Book.ID, (Return_T.return_date - Issue_T.issue_date) duration
from 
(Select ID, Timestamp issue_date from Book where Type='Issue') Issue_T,
(Select ID, Timestamp return_date from Book where Type='Return') Return_T,
Book
where Book.ID = Issue_T.ID
and Issue_T.ID = Return_T.ID
```

Comment: My biggest problem is, that i dont decide how the structure of my table is, We were getting a csv at school with some explanations and have to find a way to solve this. I was able to answer 9/10 questions, but this one driving me nuts

Comment: in that case @ypercube's solution should work for you. My Answer is towards a real world scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    s.id,   
    DATEDIFF(e.timestamp, s.timestamp) AS Days_lent
FROM 
    schedule AS s          -- start
  JOIN
    schedule AS e          -- end
      ON  s.id = e.id
      AND s.timestamp < e.timestamp 
WHERE
    s.event = 1
  AND
    e.event = 2 ;
```

Test: **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27d1e/6)**